# Why does rotation preserve angles and distance in the Euclidean plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, rotations

An angle in radians is a distance moved around a unit circle. A rotation of a point around a center of rotation, moves the point a distance around a circle around the center that goes through the point. The distance is given by the angle of the rotation multiplied by the distance from center.

So why do rotations preserve distance and angles when the distance measure is Pythagorean.

Comment: What is a Pythagoream measure?

Comment: Think about two points, not just one. If you rotate them both by the same angle, would you agree that the distance between them is the same?

Comment: Is that verbal description (which is not very precise) the verbatim definition you're meant to use, or is it an interpretation of another condition? It might also help to add to the question what you know about linear transformations, $2 \times 2$ real matrices, and/or dot products.

Comment: Is it a math question or a meta-mathematics question ?

Comment: I can see that distance and angle are preserved under rotation with paper and scissors. What I wanted was the same thing said in linear algebra.

Comment: @PeterDriscoll The most general explanation based on linear algebra should take into account the most general properties of rotation i.e. $R^TR=I$ ( equivalent $R^T=R^{-1}$) and definition of length and angle with a use of dot product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A linear algebra approach**:

Any linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$, such as a rotation about the origin, can be represented with an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, where $A\mathbf{v}$ is the output when the transformation acts on a vector $\mathbf{v}$.  Any counterclockwise rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ about the origin looks like $\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array} \right]$ where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation.  See my post [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247057/determine-the-matrix-that-rotates-the-points-in-the-plane-counter-clockwise-thro/2247084#2247084) for a justification of this fact.

First, let us investigate $\|\mathbf{v}\|$ and $\|A \mathbf{v}\|$.  If $\mathbf{v} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a \\
b \end{array} \right]$, then $\|\mathbf{v}\| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.  You can check that $A \mathbf{v} =  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(\theta)a - \sin(\theta)b \\
\sin(\theta)a + \cos(\theta)b \end{array} \right]$.  We have:

$$\|A \mathbf{v}\| = \sqrt{\Big( \cos(\theta)a - \sin(\theta)b \Big)^2 + \Big( \sin(\theta)a + \cos(\theta)b \Big)^2}$$
$$ \quad \quad  \quad \ = \sqrt{\Big( \sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) \Big)a^2 + \Big(\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) \Big)b^2}$$

And this reduces to $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \|\mathbf{v}\|$ due to the [Pythagorean identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity): $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$.  Thus, the length of any vector is preserved under any rotation.

---

To see why rotations preserve angles, use the fact that the cosine of the angle between unit vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ is equal to their [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w}$.  So let $\mathbf{v} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a \\
b \end{array} \right]$ and $\mathbf{w} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
c \\
d \end{array} \right]$ be generic unit vectors; you will find that $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w}$ and $A\mathbf{v} \cdot A \mathbf{w}$ are equal (following reduction of the latter using trig identities).

Comment: I need the distance between two arbitrary points (vectors) v and w  ∥v-w∥ = ∥A(v-w)∥ to be the same. Which follows, I think.

Comment: Yep, it does follow since $\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{w}$ is itself a vector

Answer (score 5):

Because rotation preserves the dot product.

Let $a,b$ be any vectors transformed by the rotation $R$:
$v=Ra$ and $w=Rb$.

Now $v^Tw=(Ra)^T(Rb)=a^T(R^TR)b=a^Tb $. $\ \ \ \ \ ( R^TR=I$ holds for any rotation)

We can calculate $(Ra)^T(Ra)=a^Ta=\Vert a \Vert ^2$ so length is preserved.

On the other hand $a^Tb=\Vert a \Vert \Vert b \Vert cos \angle (a,b)$ hence also preservation of the angle.