# Angle preserving property by rotation seems to be violated in desmos plot

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, triangles, rotations, angle

[This plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pg8zvdivjo) I made in desmos has the vectors $v_1=[9 \quad 0]^T$ and $v_2=[9\quad 1]^T$. If we connect the two vectors, then we can form a right triangle, where the right angle is at the point $(9,0)$ (or between $v_1$ and $v_1-v_2$). After rotating the two vectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$, $\alpha$ degrees (for a maximum effect rotate the animation by around 45 degrees) with a rotation matrix, it seems from the plot that there is not a right angle anymore between the rotated $v_1$ and rotated $v_1-v_2$. I checked this by using a sheet of paper and checking whether the angle was a 90 degree or angle or not. Furthermore, if the rotation is by 90 degrees, then the right triangle appears again over the y-axis.

I did the same in latex and the same phenomenon seems to occur there. Why is this? is there a problem with the programs? or is my intuition wrong? In my understanding, rotating both vectors is equivalent to rotating the axes, which would not break the right angle present in the original triangle. That's why I am very confused. Moreover, I am aware the rotation matrices should preserve angles as stated in this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380741/why-does-rotation-preserve-angles-and-distance-in-the-euclidean-plane) here. So, I don't really know what's going on with this construction that angles do not seem to be preserved.

Edit: I chose the value $\alpha=28^\circ$ and found a line perpendicular to $v_1$ rotated, which I found by using the negative of the inverse slope, i.e., $y=mx$, then $y=\dfrac{-x}{m}$ forms a line perpendicular to the original line.

The update plot is [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vporxgaulo).

I also upload a screenshot for reference. [image]

Comment: Odd - I do not see any change in the angle between $v_1$ and $v_1 - v_2$.

Comment: How did you measure the angles?

Comment: I used a protractor.

Comment: By the way, where did $9.93$ come from?

Comment: I found it manually, so that the line would touch the point of interest. I don't think that value matters as it has nothing to do with the slope.

Comment: I experimented a bit with the desmos plot. I used $y = -\cot\left(\frac{a}{180}\cdot\pi\right)x + v$ ($v$ is the value; it's unimportant) and I got the right slope

Comment: My results agree with yours. I guess then that $sin$ introduces some approximation error. I still find it odd, though.

Comment: The background grid "squares" don't seem to be perfectly square. (I measured the updated plot on my screen to confirm.) This would certainly cause a change in angles after rotation.

Comment: @GregMartin This is a great point. I guess to fix this problem, one would need to use a scaling matrix to adjust for the grid "squares" not being perfectly square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this effect (although visually it does appear to be true). I first tried using a protractor to measure the angle, but I got a right angle. Then I tried graphing the perpendicular line to $v_1$ by using the negative of the inverse slope. Since the slope is the tangent of the angle, my slope was the negative cotangent:

$$y=−\cot\left(\frac{a}{180} \pi\right)x + h$$

where $h$ is the rather-unimportant y-intercept.

But I found that when I calculated $h$ so that the tangent line and $v_1 - v_2$ intersected at the tip of $v_1$, the two lines were parallel.

(I believe the reason for this 'effect' is that it's harder to see right angles when they are rotated.)